# Get error on using std::string::npos

Tags: c++, g++, using

On C++, I get following error message:

```
error: ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ is not a namespace or unscoped enum
```

on this line:

```
  using std::string::npos;
```

What's wrong with it?
I'm using g++ with 2017 standard (-std=c++17)

I included < string > header.

Comment: Because `std::string` is a class

Comment: `auto npos = std::string::npos;` would achieve what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read again the error.

It tells you: "unless your are trying to alias a namespace or an unscoped enum, I will cowardly refuse to have anything to do with this `using` clause".

That is to say: don't try to define [aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) for [static constants](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) and you'll be fine.

The cited reference says:

> Using-declarations can be used to introduce **namespace members** into other namespaces and block scopes, or to introduce **base class members** into derived class definitions.

There's no mention about "introducing static constant members".

Comment: But 'cout' also is not a namespce nor enum, but we can use "using std::cout". What is difference?

Comment: The "nest" for the cout is a namespace. As suchm cout is a "namespace member" to be introduced in other namespace. By contrast, string::npos is a class member - as such, it can't be introduced everywhere but only into a derived class

Answer (score 2):

'npos' is not a namespace nor a enum. It's a static constant member.

`using std;` means "After this command I can write `string` instead of `std::string`"

Comment: s/`using std;`/`using std::string;`